# How do I cancel previous PPK file of amazon ec2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am in a big problem. actually I have given server details to third party extension support, in which I have provided them SFTP host xx.xx.xx.xx and username as ubuntu and PPK file.

Now I want to cancel the previous PPK file or some alternate way using which no one can misuse my server using those credentials. My Network administrator is responding negative on that. He said Nothing can be done now, Please let me know the solution for this problem, if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Generate a new key pair. Put its public key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Check that it works. Remove the old public key from that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you have have given the third party a copy of the private key that is used to access the server.

You could just disable access for that private key, but it would seem that other people are also using it, so your Network Administrator doesn't want to do that.

You really should have asked the 3rd party to generate their own key pair and provide you with the public key. You could then have permitted that for a short period of time and removed it, which would not have impacted on anyone else.

There isn't much you can do.

One option is to restrict access to the server by using the limit features of the authorized_keys files. If you know the ip addresses from which access is allowed, you can configure OpenSSH to only allow access from those addresses, even if the correct key is provided.

eg

https://debian-administration.org/article/685/Restricting_SSH_logins_to_particular_IP_addresses

You could also experiment with the "Match" options in sshd_config to prevent access from users who match certain criteria.

Bottom line: never share private keys. Every user should be using their own key pair.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. IP restriction is a good trick there.

Answer (score 0):

This will be slightly complicate process. AWS has a full page [talking about keypair](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html)

- The public key is stored under `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys`or ubuntu. If you use other OS, please check AWS documentation on the location of the public key.
- Make snapshot backup before you do anything
- Launch the backup snapshot (to another IP), make changes, test whether you can login
- Then make another snapshot on the current server before you make changes
- Make the changes

You may use some guide here [Change key pair for ec2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881469/change-key-pair-for-ec2-instance)

Always create extra snapshot if you want to make changes, it is the final fallback if you mess stuff up.

UPDATE: 
Actually there is a CATCH here. If your AWS EC2 instance is using instance-storage(e.g. m3, c3), you cannot change the keypair. What you can do is create snapshot from it, make changes on the snapshot, launch a new instance from there .